# Symfony. Не удается подключить CSS/JS

Tags: php, symfony

Установил Symfony 3.0.4, в каталоге web разместил папку css с файлами стилей.
В base.html.twig прописал:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

Но когда перехожу обновляю страницу, в консоле пишет что мой app.css 404 not found.
Я перечитал всю документацию, посмотрел кучу видео и прочитал много статей из неофициальных источников и этот способ работает везде! но только не у меня.
Для убедительности установил symfony-demo проект и там тоже не работает, причем изначально там прописан такой же код что я написал выше.
Может что-то не так с веб-сервером? я уже не знаю что делать.
Исходников никаких нет, проделываю всё в новом (чистом) проекте.
Ещё пробовал чистить кеш - не помогло.

Вот видео о том как подключить, у меня не работает этот способ.
https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony/layout-assets

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/framework/css/app.css') }}"/>

Comment: нет, app.css находится в web/css/app.css
путь прописал точно, т.к. даже IDE ведет к файлу при клике.

Comment: Я ради интереса установил Symfony и попробовал — всё гуд. Так если `<link>` выводится на страницу и в `href` правильный путь, то здесь два варианта: либо файла там нет, либо глючит сервер.

Comment: Файл есть это точно т.к. даже favicon не отображается. Скорее всего сервер чудит. Переустановил XAMPP, прописал vhost.

Comment: УРА! Заработало. 
Я - тупой идиот. Когда добавлял virtualhost в apache, в качестве DocumentRoot указывал ../web/app_dev.php, а нужно было всю папку web, без файла.
Спасибо всем за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда добавлял virtualhost в apache, в качестве DocumentRoot указывал ../web/app_dev.php, а нужно было всю папку web, без файла.